# Increase the cell size of a particular Row -JAVAFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to resize a particular `cell` in `TableView` in a particular `Row`.

The code i use,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableColors extends Application {

    TableView<String> tView = new TableView<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableColumn<String, String> tcName = new TableColumn("name");
        TableColumn<String, String> tcName1 = new TableColumn("name1");
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
        tView.setItems(items);
        tView.getColumns().add(tcName);
        tView.getColumns().add(tcName1);

        tView.setColumnResizePolicy((param) -> true);
        Platform.runLater(() -> customResize());

        tcName.setCellValueFactory((p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue()));
        tcName.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<String, String>, TableCell<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new TableCell<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);//*don't forget!
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);
                            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        } else {
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(tView, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void customResize() {
        try {
            TableColumn<?, ?> col = tView.getColumns().get(0);
            col.setPrefWidth(150);
        } catch (Exception r) {
            r.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

when i run this complete `name` **column** size is increased(as expected).

Instead i want to increase only the size of the cell which contains "**Three**".

Am not sure ,What code should i incorporate to make it work in this way.

How can i solve this?

Comment: You want cells with different widths in the same column? Sorry, but that is not something `TableView` supports. It would require heavy modifications of the `TableView` `Skin` to achieve this effect... You could of course display a `graphic` with a size different to other cells in the `TableView` or similar things, but `TableView` will still make sure all cells in a row have equal height and all cells in a column have equal width...

Comment: but how do you want this to work? that particular column will have the width of the longest cell? so you wouldn't even notice same with others too

Comment: @Elltz Am trying to do a workaround for Merging cells by increasing the cell width to table width and shrinking other column cell's width . I am expecting it to work as how excel does merge two or more cells.

Comment: hmm that might be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this logic

Let your cell DataHolder implement something like this

```
public class DataHolder{
   boolean cellOverlaps = false; //tells the cell whether its string overlaps others
   int rowPos = -1;// the vertical position 
   int columnPos =-1; //its column position
   boolean startPoint = false;//whether its the start point
   //in other words it begins from here hence its right border we care
   String text = ""
}
```

So what you do basically, is in your `updateIndex()`, or `updateItem()` methods or your `Commit()` method of your cell, (use commit()) you calculate the width of the cell by `Cell.prefWidth(-1)` or `Cell.getWidth()`, after you get the space your text is occupying in your first cell, compare that to your width if its > then you trim the text and make it overlap. here you have something like

```
dataHolder.cellOverlaps = true;
dataHolder.startPoint = true;//other overlapping cell will have this false
dataHolder.rowPost = getIndex();
dataHolder.columnPos = getTableView().getColumns().indexof(getTableColumn());
```

so now you look for cells in row `getIndex()` with columnPos > the startPoint

and you change the styles of the cell for example the starting cell with have a transparent border right color

```
 -fx-border-color: black black black transparent;
```

now the other overlaping celss will have the left transparent

```
-fx-border-color: black transparent black black;
```

and you set the text of the remaining string to the cell. if possible change the background of the TableRow so it matches your cell hence you do not get to see the divider line.

try it and see, wanted to drop a demo but do not have much time though.

Hope if helps